# Polyemer unit testing

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have problems testing the next component:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">

<link rel="import" href="../maps/maps-api.html">    

<dom-module id="address-input">
  <template>
    <maps-api on-api-load="_onApiLoad"></maps-api>
    <paper-input
     id="address"
     name$="[[name]]"
     label$="[[label]]"
     placeholder="[[placeholder]]"
     required$="[[required]]"
     value="{{value}}"
     disabled="{{disabled}}"
     always-float-label
     on-keydown="_onKeyDown"></paper-input>
</template>

  <script>
    (function () {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'address-input',

        properties: {
          value: {
            type: String,
            notify: true
          },

          name: {
            type: Object
          },

          label: {
            type: Object
          },

          lastAutoCompleteResult: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true,
            observer: '_onLastAutoCompleteResultChange'
          },

          disabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            value: false
          },

          required: {
            type: Boolean,
            value: false
          },

          map: {
            type: Object
          }
        },

        attached: function () {
          if (!this._autocomplete && window.google && window.google.maps) this._onApiLoad();
        },

        _onApiLoad: function () {
          //DOES SOMETHING
        }

        _onLastAutoCompleteResultChange: function () {
          //DOES SOMETHING
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

and that module includes maps-api

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bower_components/google-apis/google-maps-api.html">

<!--
Wrapper for the google maps api component in order to avoid copying the
API key everywhere just import this component instead.
-->
<dom-module id="maps-api">
  <template>
    <google-maps-api api-key="[[apiKey]]" version="3"></google-maps-api>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function () {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'maps-api',

        properties: {
          apiKey: {
            type: String,
            value: APP_CONFIG.gmapsApiKey
          },
        }
      })
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

this is the test:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <title>my-greeting-basic</title>

  <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/web-component-tester/browser.js"></script>

  <!-- Import the element to test -->
  <link rel="import" href="../elements/common/address-input.html">


</head>
<maps-api on-api-load="_onApiLoad"></maps-api>
<body>

<test-fixture id="address-input">
  <template>        
    <address-input

      id="address"
      value="430 W Erie St"
    ></address-input>

  </template>
</test-fixture>

<script>

  describe('address-input', function (done) {

    var addressInput, id, value;

    beforeEach(function () {
      APP_CONFIG = {};
      APP_CONFIG = {gmapsApiKey:"someKey"};

      addressInput = fixture('address-input');
    });

    test('should enable when disable is false', function () {

      addressInput.disabled = false;
      var element = document.getElementById('address');
      var isDisabled = element.disabled;
      assert.equal(isDisabled, false);
    });

  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is the global variable APP_CONFIG is undefined forthe component map-api

I get this error:

Error: APP_CONFIG is not defined
   at /components/elements/maps/maps-api.html:23
   at /components/elements/maps/maps-api.html:27

(I'm using Mocha,Chai and Sinon)

what's the correct way to set global variables in polymer testing?

Comment: Try `window.APP_CONFIG`. I think maybe your variable inside `beforeEach` gets local scope?

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work